# How to match a static list of system names against logs in Loki/Grafana to find inactive systems?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-variable, promtail, logql

I'm working with Loki/Grafana and trying to modify a query that currently identifies systems that are considered "offline." A system is deemed offline if it has sent a log within the last 7 days but not in the last 5 minutes. However, I want to change this logic to compare the systems active in the last 5 minutes against a fixed list and display those that are part of the list but haven't sent a log in the last 5 minutes.

The fixed list of systems is provided as a JSON file through promtail to Loki/Grafana like this:

```json
{
  "allSystems": ["mrs2-14", "mrs2-11", "mrs2-103"],
  "totalCount": 3
}
```

And I can query this JSON data in Grafana using the following query:

```
{job="mrs_system_info"} |= ``
```

What I need is to cross-reference this static list of systems with the logs to determine which ones haven't reported in the last 5 minutes. The current query I'm using to find "offline" systems is:

```
count by(system) (count_over_time({job="mrs_error_list"} |~ "" [7d]))
unless
count by(system) (count_over_time({job="mrs_error_list"} |~ "" [5m]))
```

How can I alter this query to check against the allSystems array from my JSON data instead of the last 7 days logs?

I expect the final output to show a list of systems that are in the allSystems array but have not sent logs in the past 5 minutes.

Any suggestions on how to correctly implement this logic with Loki/Grafana would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with your new data format. Functionality of logql is very limited around json arrays.

Comment: But if you can change logs provided, passing a log line per each system would allow you to reuse existing query.

Comment: In theory: use join transformation, but transform that list first so you will be able to join and then just filter tranformatiom and list only records without join. Of course implementation will be more complicated and complex.

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution from markalex, so that i was able to use the same query